# Search for a tag's name inside of a cell inside of each row

Tags: javascript, html

So pretty much I have it to were it's searching for the innerHTML of the td in question in each row....however I'm trying to grab the input name attribute from below

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Client"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what i have so far

```
var q = document.getElementById("q");
var v = q.value.toLowerCase();
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var on = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var fullname = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    fullname = fullname[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    if (fullname) {
        if (v.length == 0 || 
               (v.length < 3 && fullname.indexOf(v) == 0) || 
               (v.length >= 3 && fullname.indexOf(v) > -1)) {
            rows[i].style.display = "";
            on++;
        } else {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
var n = document.getElementById("noresults");
if (on == 0 && n) {
    n.style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("qt").innerHTML = q.value;
} else {
    n.style.display = "none";
}
```

However right now it's only indicating within the `td`.... How do I get the above to look for the name of the input inside of the td?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of the `name` attribute of the `<input>` in a given `<td>`, or are you asking how to find the `<input>` whose `name` attribute has a given value?

Comment: i'm trying to get the value of the name attribute within the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a lot of code for that. On most modern browser this works.

```js
//For 1 value
myInput = document.querySelector('#tablename td [name="Client"]');
console.log(myInput);

//For more values
myInput2 = document.querySelectorAll('#tablename td [name="Client"]'); 
console.log(myInput2); //it's an array now

//Like this?
myInput3 = document.querySelector('#tablename td [name]');
if(myInput3.getAttribute('name') == 'Client'){
    myInput3.setAttribute('name', 'something');
}
console.log(myInput3.parentElement);
```

```html
<table id="tablename">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="Client"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok...this is closer...but say that i need the "client" portion to be changeable as in it get's a value from an event.target? how would this work? the reason for this is there is actually inner html in the <tr> i need to get based upon that <input> name.

Comment: Ummm nooo maybe I wasn't clear hahaha.  First I actually need to search the name of the iput inside the td. then if (input's name == 'value') I need it to bring back the TD that input is in

Comment: Just add parentElement to it to get the td.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the `<td>` element, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to get a reference to the `<input>` (assuming it's the only or first `<input>` descendant) and then [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to get the value of the `name` attribute:

```js
// You already have a reference to the <td>
const td = document.querySelector('td');

// Get the <input>
const input = td.querySelector('input');

// Get its `name` attribute
const name = input.getAttribute('name');
console.log('name is "%s"', name);
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="Client"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok however with the existing code how would this work? because the constructs given...do not work currently with the code i'm using.